# "Counter" cannot be resolved to a variable error?

Tags: java, variables

```
 public class arryTable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Index\tValue");

        int paco[]={1,2,3,4,5};

        for(int counter = 0;
                counter < paco.length;       
                counter++);

        System.out.println(counter + "\t" + paco[counter]);

    }

}
```

I get "counter cannot be resolved to a variable". Has the last "counter" underlined. Thank you

Comment: Remove the semicolon 
for(int counter = 0;
                counter < paco.length;       
                counter++)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `for` loop ends with a semicolon, when it should be scoping a set of instructions:

```
for(int counter = 0; counter < paco.length; counter++) { // < Note open curly bracket
    System.out.println(counter + "\t" + paco[counter]);
} // < Note close curly bracket
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the semi-colon after the `for` loop. It acts as an empty statement.

Answer (score 1):

Remove ";" at the end of the "for" loop.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `;` after the `for`. And then,

You need to learn

1) Debugging techniques.

2) Syntax of the language.

3) Using google efficiently.

Comment: You're probably right, thank you.